# SQL to Compare Data from Two Tables from Separate Databases Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Canadian db with a customer table and a US db with a customer table. Table structure is same. If a job for a US Customer gets worked on
in Canada then that customer record will be created in the Candian DB. However when something changes for the customer, for example their address, user
will only update one database and forget the other. Then down the line there are 2 addresses and it causes confusion.

As a way to audit this I'm trying to compare the records between the 2 tables to see if 1) cust_code exists in both, if so what is different.

I'm trying this but not sure if this is the right route to take. It only gives me records from 1 and not in the other. But I want to compare if the same cust_code is in both but with for example an address being different.

```
select *
from 
(
( select cust_code, cust_address, job from cust
  minus 
  select cust_code, cust_address, job from cust@canada)
union all
( select cust_code, cust_address, job from cust@canada
  minus
  select cust_code, cust_address, job from cust)
)
```

Comment: That query should give you the customers that exist only in one of the DB's and those that are different in the other.  I would add an indicator showing which DB provided the record.  Create a db fiddle with some sample data if you still have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

> But I want to compare if the same cust_code is in both but with for example an address being different.

Why not just use `join`?

```
select c.*, cc.*
from cust c join
     cust@canada cc
     on c.cust_code = cc.cust_code
where c.job <> cc.job or
      c.address <> cc.address;
```

Comment: Don't you think something's missing?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille . . . It is very tempting to flag your comment as totally unproductive.  If there is an issue that you see, you should be explicit.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I am not a big fan of selecting `*`, especially when the two tables have columns with the same name. No need to show the `cust_code` twice, either - since it should be the same (by the join condition). Rather: `select c.cust_code, c.job, cc.job AS ca_job, ...` to clearly show the "job" and the "Canada job" side by side, and same for address. Other than that, your join condition doesn't handle the possibility that the job (or the address, or both) is `null` in one table or the other (or both).

Comment: The join will exclude customer codes existing only in one of the DB's.  I  mentioned it to the OP, but he seems to be out of the building.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille . . . That what the OP has asked for.  I added the relevant part of the question to make it clear to YOU.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this. Decode function allows to compare even null values.

```sql
select *
from (
  select 
        us.cust_address "us.cust_address", ca.cust_address "ca.cust_address"
      , decode(us.cust_address, ca.cust_address, 'Match', 'Mismatch') "cust_address.MATCH"
      , us.job "us.job", ca.job "ca.job"
      , decode(us.job, ca.job, 'Match', 'Mismatch') "job.MATCH"
  from cust us
  join cust@canada ca on (us.cust_code = ca.cust_code)
)
where "cust_address.MATCH" = 'Mismatch'
    or "job.MATCH" = 'Mismatch'
;
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
  from 
(
( select 'US' as origin, cust_code, cust_address, job from cust
  minus 
  select 'US' as origin, cust_code, cust_address, job from cust@canada)
union all
( select 'CAN' as origin, cust_code, cust_address, job from cust@canada
  minus
  select 'CAN' as origin, cust_code, cust_address, job from cust)
)
```